# Dynamic url segment name in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In fact i'm looking for way to fetch url segment and replace it to another string name for example   `/setting` show it in my view `الضبط` in Arabic

After research i found `substr_replace` or `str_ireplace`can achieve that 
as the following:

```
  $seg2 = request()->segment(2);

 ($seg2 == 'setting') ? $seg2 = str_ireplace($seg2,'الضبط',$seg2) : $seg2 = str_ireplace($seg2,'another_segment_name', $seg2);
```

I see this approach is very bad if i have many of different routes can to be in `$seg2` place .

If there any other way can achieve that please help me ,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @The Alpha for your help in fact i have been achieved my needs now but i did some changes to achieve it i will show it for help any somebody else needs to do that

at first i created `segments.php` file in `resources/lang/ar` and change local language to `ar` in `config/app.php`

and in `segments.php`

```
<?php

// Segments Array for navigation paths on view  

return [
  'users' => 'المستخدمين',  //maybe to be seg2
  'settings' => 'الضبط',   //also maybe to be seg2
];
```

and in my view

```
<!-- Simple condition to check if user on segment 2 or not and fetch the proper segment name according to incoming segment in url -->
            {{(request()->segment(2) != '') ? trans('segments.'.request()->segment(2)) : '' }}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can use a localized file, what I mean hera that, you may use [Laravel's Localization](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/localization) feature. For example, put a `messages.php` file in `resources/lang/ar` folder and can map `key => value` pairs like:

```
<?php

return [
    'settings' => 'الضبط',
    'otherKey' => 'some Arabic word'
];
```

Then, you may use it like the following (it'll replace the settings with appropriate value):

```
echo trans('messages.' . request()->segment(2));

// Or use this for blade template
{{ trans('messages.' . request()->segment(2)) }}
```

To make it working you need to set locale (default language) to `ar` in `config/app.php` file but you may automize it, I mean, you can set the locale at the runtime. Hope You got the idea, just read the documentation properly. By the way, this is only an idea, you may do it differently if necessary.